# Load module dynamically in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I don't know how to dynamically load a module in Python. I'm trying to do the following.

```
package = __import__("multiprocessing")
module = getattr(package, "Queue")
struct_class = globals()[str(module)]
```

The third line is causing problems. Now struct_class is supposed to be the Queue class but it throws the error:

```
KeyError: '<bound method BaseContext.Queue of 
<multiprocessing.context.DefaultContext object at 0x7f3706a71898>>'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `struct_class = module()`

Comment: This worked! Thank you